# How do we auto-sort datalist in google spreadsheet?

Tags: google-sheets

Below is my code:

```
function autoSort(){

  var spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  Logger.log(spreadSheet);
  var workSheet = spreadSheet.getSheetByName("Rough");
  Logger.log(workSheet)

  var lastRow = workSheet.getLastRow() - 1;
  var lastCol = workSheet.getLastColumn();
  Logger.log(lastRow);
  Logger.log(lastCol);


  range = workSheet.getRange(2,1,lastRow, lastCol);
  Logger.log(range);

  range.sort({column: lastCol, ascending: false});

}

function onEdit(e){
  var row = e.range.getRow();
  var col = e.range.getColumn();

  Logger.log(row);
  Logger.log(col);

  if(!(col === lastCol && row >=2)) return

  autoSort();
}
```

With this I am able to sort my data list when I run the script however, it doesn't automatically sort when I add a new row value.

Below is my data list in which I am working:

Roll No Names           Locations
55657   Buggy           OP
123 Shaks           OP
45654   Nami            OP
114151  Madara          N
7874    Frodo           LOTR
21341   Phantom         DOTA
114745  Mercurial   DOTA
12243   Light           DN
6768    L           DN
2342    Ryuzaki         DN
99999   Goku            DBZ
558858  Vegeta          DBZ
111111  Ichigo          BTYW
88888   Uliquora    BTYW
98478   Meepo           DOTA

I went through youtube videos and this was what I could get. The onevent function ie, onEdit(e) seems to be not executing at all, as the log of row and col doesn't appear in log.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the issue is that `lastCol` was not recognized in `onEdit(e)` since at that point it was not declared. A quick solution would be to use `e` to create that variable:

```js
function onEdit(e){
  var row = e.range.getRow();
  var col = e.range.getColumn();
  var lastCol = e.source.getLastColumn();

  Logger.log(row);
  Logger.log(col);
  Logger.log(lastCol);

  if(!(col === lastCol && row >=2)) return
  
  autoSort();
}
```

This is how it looks after correcting it:

[image: Example]

---

The function `autosort()` was unchanged.